# How to View Certificate Chain in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, tls1.2

**My Setup:**

I'm configuring SSL on a webserver hosted on a very "secure" server. I can't install any new software, I can only test from localhost or a domain name that redirects to 127.0.0.1 (edited the host file), and I have access to a limited set of tools. I can only use Java keytool, and Internet Explorer 11.

**My Problem:**

When I access a webpage hosted by my webserver I get a "There was a problem with this websites security certificate" error as well as an option to proceed to the page anyways. Proceeding to the page directs me to the same error page but without the option to proceed (The button does nothing but remove itself).

[image: There was a problem with this websites security certificate]

**My Question:**

How do I view the certificate chain in Internet Explorer 11? In Chrome all I have to do is click the lock but the lock isn't appearing in the IE11 address bar.

**Solutions I've Tried:**

1. Go to Gear Icon->Internet Options->Advanced uncheck "Check for publisher's...", "Check for server cert...", "Check for signature...", and "Warn about certificate...". Accessing the webpage still produces the same problem as described above.
2. Right click white space on error page, click properties. Click certificates button. The button does nothing, no dialog shows up, no errors show up, it just clicks and nothing happens.
3. I know the error isn't being caused by a domain name mismatch as I edited the host file to map the domain name to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot view the cert from the interstitial, it seems. You can however, cautiously, click "Continue to this website", then using File / Properties, the Certificate button will work.

Comment: @vcsjones "cautiously" how? How can you assess if the website you are about to visit is legit or not if you can not even see the certificate? That seems really a UI shortcoming, not being able to see the certificate before connecting to it, and being already maybe diverted to some bad place.

Comment: I think it was a joke? Also it's kind of vindicating that I'm not the only developer that hates this IE11 "Safety Feature". Anyways, @vcjones I'll try your solution on Tuesday when I get access to the environment again, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @JHam troubleshooting TLS problems (please stop saying SSL, TLS was invented nearly **20** years ago as a replacement for SSL) without even having access to `openssl` is probably my definition of living in hell. Not being able to use the appropriate tools to do one job should be brought up the chain of command. Using a browser to debug low level TCP/TLS problem is the wrong way to do it, even if you can not do anything about that at your level, you should bring up the issue and explaining how much time you loose just because you can not use the tools of the trade at hand.

Answer (score 1):

> There was a problem with this websites security certificate

To work around this issue, you need to install the SSL certificate on the client computer. To do this, follow these steps:

1. In Windows Internet Explorer, click Continue to this website (not recommended).
2. Click the Certificate Error button to open the information window.
3. Click View Certificates, and then click Install Certificate.
4. On the warning message that appears, click Yes to install the certificate.

More details, please refer check ["There is a problem with this website's security certificate" when you try to visit a secured website in Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/931850/there-is-a-problem-with-this-website-s-security-certificate-when-you-t)

> How do I view the certificate chain in Internet Explorer 11?

You could refer to the following steps to view the certificates in Internet Explorer:

1. In the Internet Explorer window, click on Tools and then Internet Options at the bottom of the drop-down menu.
2. In the new window that appears, click on the Content tab at the top in the middle of the other tabs.
3. Click on the Certificates button near the middle of the window.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the only way you can view the certificate is to first continue to the website.

- Click `Continue to this website (not recommended)`
- You will now be taken to the website and you'll see a red address bar with "Certificate Error" on the right (see below).
- Click on "Certificate Error" and you will see an info screen.
- Click the link at the bottom to "View certificates".

[image: Certificate Error]

[image: View Certificates]

Answer (score -3):

Please install ssl certificate using Certbot Commandline with Cpanel accessibility with putty software

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. This answer is very basic instructions for users to install a cert (note they also say they cannot install any extra software to get certbot added or even mentioning if CPanel is preset). The user is asking a different question though - they want to know how to view the certificate chain, not how to install a cert.